# How to increase accuracy of simple regression neural network?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, accuracy

I'm (very new, and) struggling to improve the accuracy of a simple neural network to predict a synthetic function.

I started from a neural network to predict sin, as described here: [Why does this neural network in keras fail so badly?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230298/why-does-this-neural-network-in-keras-fail-so-badly).  I got this working perfectly, but I cannot get the solution to adapt to my own function.

I am trying to predict (something very similar to) the angle theta in

```
cos(theta) = O / H (H is input, O is constant)
```

The closes I have gotten is the below, where 'r+' is training points, and 'bo' is the predictions over those same points.

I've tried thousands of neurons, multiple layers, hundreds of thousands of epochs (I'm not at all worried about over-fitting, my first step is to replicate as near as possible the actual input data).  I thought over-fitting to a perfect match would be easy - what am I doing wrong???

[image]

Test data here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgspNAHPoHu6kDQHyOQzkPCt8fop

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
#from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

r = Sequential()

def setup_nn():
    r.add(Dense(5000, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="sigmoid"))
    #r.add(Dense(200, kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="sigmoid"))
    r.add(Dense(units=1, activation="linear"))

    sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0002, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
    adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-10, decay=0)
    r.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

def read_data():
    filename = "1d-ik.csv"
    with open(filename) as inf:
        # Skip header
        #next(inf)
        colDist = []
        colB1Z = []
        colB2Z = []
        for line in inf:
            # Read data, using python, into our features
            dist,b1Z,b2Z = line.strip().split(",")
            colDist.append(float(dist))
            colB1Z.append(float(b1Z) / -80)
            colB2Z.append(float(b2Z))

        train_X = colDist
        train_Y = colB1Z

        #y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        #train_X = y_scaler.fit_transform(train_Y)
        train_X = train_X;
        return train_X,train_Y

#############################################################################

setup_nn()
plt.interactive(False)

X,Y = read_data()
r.fit(X, Y, batch_size=10, epochs=5000)

pred_Y = r.predict(X)

plt.plot(X, Y, 'r+')
plt.plot(X, pred_Y, 'bo')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

So, there turned out to be several steps that significantly improved my result - most of which could have been found by analyzing the working solution (from the linked question) with changes I assumed were better in my code:

1) scaling input (X) to 0-1.  In the original code, X is always between 0 - 1, In the code above, input (distance) is from 0-80

2) Removed normalizing of (Y).  Contrary to all the advice I have seen - The original code learnt sin(X) * 10 well, but failed learning sin(X).  I found even better results when scaling higher (eg cos * 100 worked better than cos * 10)

3) Use the ADAM optimizer.  SGD seemed to learn sin ok, but failed on cosine & more complicated graphs

4) More epochs.  Sometimes, the ADAM would appear to get stuck, with the error metric even occasionally rising.  However, after a while (10-30 epochs) learning would resume and even pick up pace.

The take-away:

Rules of thumb are great, but experimentation is important!

Always work forward from a working solution ONE STEP AT A TIME!!!